# Docker Image Ubuntu 20.04 input stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: docker, shell, docker-compose

I have built a Docker Compose project which worked without problems in my container until Ubuntu 18.04.

Now I have updated the project to version Ubunut 20.04 and I get the following error message when starting a shell script Docker Entrypoint:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -f /usr/local/etc/piler/config-site.php ]
then
        sleep 20
        cd /root/mailpiler/piler/
        cp util/postinstall.sh util/postinstall.sh.bak
        sed -i "s/   SMARTHOST=.*/   SMARTHOST="\"$MAILSERVER_DOMAIN\""/" util/postinstall.sh
        sed -i 's/   WWWGROUP=.*/   WWWGROUP="www-data"/' util/postinstall.sh

        sed -i "s/ "

        echo -e "y\n\n$PILER_DB_HOST\n$MYSQL_DATABASE\n$MYSQL_USER\n$MYSQL_PASSWORD\n$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\n\n\nY\nY\n" | make postinstall

        # echo -e "y\n$PILER_DB_HOST\n\n$MYSQL_DATABASE\n$MYSQL_USER\n$MYSQL_PASSWORD\n$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\n\n\n\ny\ny\n" | make postinstall

fi
```

The command `echo -e "y\n\n$PILER_DB_HOST\n$MYSQL_DATABASE\n$MYSQL_USER\n$MYSQL_PASSWORD\n$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\n\n\nY\nY\n" | make postinstall` went without problems so far but since Ubuntu 20.04 the following error is coming:

```
app_1  | This is the postinstall utility for piler
app_1  | It should be run only at the first install. DO NOT run on an existing piler installation!
app_1  |
app_1  |
app_1  | Continue? [Y/N] [N]
app_1  |
app_1  | Please enter the webserver groupname [www-data]
app_1  | Please enter mysql hostname [localhost]
app_1  | Please enter mysql database [piler]
app_1  | Please enter mysql user name [piler] stty: 
'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

**'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
app_1  | make: *** [Makefile:126: postinstall] Error 1**

The script:

https://bitbucket.org/jsuto/piler/src/master/util/postinstall.sh.in

I'm sure it has something to do with the stty mode and Docker, but I don't know how to fix it.

By the way the script works without dockerized under Ubuntu 20.04 without problems.

My Docker-Compose file:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/images
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "25:25"
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/piler-local:/usr/local/etc/piler
      - ./docker/data/piler-data:/var/piler

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Did try to add `tty: true` within your docker-compose file?  Another people related the same problem on github, [check here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1876#issuecomment-604006192).

Comment: stdin_open: true
tty: true

I already tried that and it didn't work. Same mistake. :(